# How to access column values in tuple inside for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, tuples

I have two data frames called `Exmil_df` and `Schedule_df`.

When I execute following code I get all column values in `Schedule_df` dataframe in `subrow[1]`. But I have separate data transformations to done in different columns. How can I access columns separately where as in data frame?

```
for row in Exmil_df.iterrows():
    for subrow in Schedule_df.iterrows():
        print(subrow[1])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.[iterrows](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html)() returns a tuple of (index, row) so when you're accessing subrow[1  you're actually accessing the entire row object that's why you're getting all columns

Try this:

```
for (index1,row) in Exmil_df.iterrows():
    for (index2, subrow) in Schedule_df.iterrows():
        #You can access the column by calling subrow[colName]
        print(subrow[colName])
```